# PHP script suddenly outputting memory size of X bytes exhausted

Tags: php, curl

Ive been running this script all day and there havnt been any issues. The script is converting images to JPG. There are about 6000 images. Up until now the script will process about 50 images before stopping. When it stops i just run the script again. So far its done about 2000 images, but now im suddenly out of memory.

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
```

This is the line that gets output in the error log. I can no longer run the script

I have tried restarting the entire server and it has not fixed the issue. I also tried increasing the max memory from 128mb to 512mb in the php.ini and it hasnt had an effect. The script has been runnning fine until now and now its not working.

The script is running some curl requests then generating images and updating a few database tables. Its quite a large script for processing, but its had no errors up until now.

Comment: Is this script being run via the command line, or via an HTTP request?

Comment: im running it using wget via command line

Comment: There may be memory limits in whatever web server you are using that are overriding whatever PHP wants to use. Also, have you restarted the webserver? I don't think configuration changes will take effect until you do.

Comment: did you check what image is causing this? Remember that GD is going to decompress the image into a raw bitmap in ram. If a 50,000 x 50,000 image slipped into the system, you're going to end up needing ~7gigs of ram to store that raw bitmap in memory.

Comment: There is a possibility that there could be some 4K sized images in this directory. I dont have access though. I tried a try catch but it doesnt work. Is there some way that i can try to process the image and if it hits memory issues catch the error rather than crash?

Answer (score -1):

This is something you wouldn't wanna use in a production environment, but usually does the trick for me for memory consuming one time operations.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1 );
```

Comment: hmm this is working now, but i dont like the idea of this script eventually taking over the entire system. What could have caused it to suddenly require so much memory? I was fine with 128mb a few minutes ago?

Comment: Allowing php to use how much memory that it wants should not be a solution. Finding the code causing the memory leak should be the approach

Comment: That's why I mention it could work for one time operations, but isn't a real solution for a production environment.